# how to embed the vlclib to exoplayer?

Tags: android, media, vlc, exoplayer

I am using exoplayer for my media player application. I want to use vlcLib for my android app in exoplayer support. please help me i am stucked in it from couple of months.

Comment: try one of the official libvlc android samples, unrelated to exoplayer

Comment: will it help me?

Comment: I want to implement the vclib with exo because exo is much easier than vclib to implement with rich functionality but limited.